# How to use $limit and $sort with Q.nbind() in mongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, q

I am using Q module in my app. I want to use $limit and $sort function for my query for mongoDB,
I am also using Q.nbind() for making query

```
var Q = require('q');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var RequestPrayers = mongoose.model('requestPrayers');
var RPrayerfind = Q.nbind(RequestPrayers.find, RequestPrayers);



function getSingleRParyerInfo(FrndID){

    var id = FrndID
    var prayerInfo={prayersInfo:''};
    return RPrayerfind({userID:id, is_notPrivate:true})
        //   return   find()
//  ^^^^^^ Rule 1

        .then(function(Prayers) {
//  ^^^^^ Rule 3
            if (!Prayers){
                prayerInfo.prayersInfo = '';
                //   console.log(User)
            }else{
                prayerInfo.prayersInfo = Prayers;
                //console.log(User)
            }
            return prayerInfo;
//      ^^^^^^ Rule 3b
        });
}
```

Please what should I use to get my desired result

return RPrayerfind({userID:id, is_notPrivate:true}).limit(2);

OR

return RPrayerfind({userID:id, is_notPrivate:true},{$limit:2})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very simple just have a look at following code:

```
    var q = require('q');
    var findSomeThing = q.nbind(SomeThing.find,SomeThing);

    SomeThing({"someId":"someIdValue"},{},{limit:2}).done(function(data){

        //2 records will be retrieved here
        console.log(data);


    });
```

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

You can simple use it like this

RPrayerFind({userId:1},{},{'$limit':10,'$skip':300})

Comment: its not working all the data is shown no limit is applied plus dat contain only ID of the prayer rather than returning the whole info object

Comment: well, that's how you use it with mongoose, their API doc suggests. Are you sure you are doing it right?

Comment: arrgh!! sorry @Zeeshan posted the right answer, I missed one variable pass.

So it goes like this, {//The search criteria},{//variables you want to get},{//conditions like limit sort.}